# Reputations went down

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

Last evening i was answering so many questions. Most of my answers got up voted. I got around 91 in my reputations. But when i checked in the morning reputation was 46. It seemed so strange for me. How could this happen?

NOTE: I haven't got any down votes that would reduce my reputation since last evening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the fluctuation in your rep status was due to flagging and cleanup activities.

Let me explain.

- [Screenshots taken in ubuntu 14.04 LTS are not opening in windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611327/screenshots-taken-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-are-not-opening-in-windows-7/611333#611333)

You had 20 rep on this.  Your answer was flagged as a duplicate of another answer.  Indeed, another answer on the same question was similarly removed since it just repeated the same information.  If you can substantially differentiate you answer from the others, we can reinstate it.  Change it and flag and it can be undeleted.  Where answers are identical, too brief or just verging on being a comment we also remove.  In this situation you hit all three criteria.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/611319/restoring-old-boot-screen/611322#611322

You had 25 rep on this one. This one you answered saying the answer was given on another question.  The flag said that the questions were identical - I agree.  Thus, what you should have done in this situation is flag and/or comment that the question was a duplicate.  We can then close the question as a duplicate.  Your answer and the accepted vote score was removed to allow redirection to work.  This is where someone searches for a question and stack exchange automatically redirects them to the correct answer.

Conclusions.

Don't be too down-hearted.  Just remember to try to differentiate your answers from others.  Explain fully - dont just give brief link only type or just answers that don't answer the who-what-why-where-when explanations.  We all have been there at the beginning.  "The rep will come"

Comment: Wow! How this works is just mind blowing. Thanks for the heads up. Will try to improve the answers.

Comment: @kisanme It can be a little confusing at first. We *aren't* a forum. If you ever have any questions you can take a look in the [help], ask here on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/), drop by [chat] or search on the network wide [meta.se]. Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!